# Debugging Symfony 3.4 live - 403 page, possible User Roles issue

Tags: php, symfony, http-status-code-403, user-roles

I am getting a 403 error when clicking on a link to the */admin/stats* page when logged  with User Role: ROLE_EXPL which should have access to the page.  It works fine for ROLE_ADMIN which also has access to this page.

Looking at the code, there are three user roles and the link to the page in question  */admin/stats* is not displayed on the menu for the user role ROLE_PASS but is for the others.  However, this link gives a 403 error for ROLE_EXPL but works fine for ROLE_ADMIN

Can anyone advise on where to start with debugging this?

**Code:**
security.yaml

```
security:

    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Pass:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        pass_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Pass
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: pass_provider
            switch_user: true
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                default_target_path: /home
                always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login
            logout_on_user_change: true
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /home

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_PASS:           ROLE_USER
        ROLE_EXPL:           ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:          ROLE_USER

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: '%https%' }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: '%https%' }
        - { path: ^/forgotten_password, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: '%https%' }
        - { path: ^/reset_password, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: '%https%' }
```

**Required outcome:**

ROLE_EXPL Should have access to the page */admin/stats*

Comment: What do you want to achieve? 403 indicates "Forbidden", and if this works using another user with the proper roles, everything sounds fine?

Comment: The  link  for that user should not be forbidden.  The links shows in the admin panel for that user but why is it coming as forbidden?  How do I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add an extra line or "security pattern" to the **security.yaml** file for the */admin/stats* URL.

As Nico pointed out, only users with the role ROLE_ADMIN had access to the paths starting with */admin*

I therefore added the below line below the  *^/admin* path but this did not work.  I moved it above that path and it worked but then broke the page for the other user, therefore **the order of the security patterns is very important**

```
{ path: ^/admin/stats, roles: ROLE_EXPL, requires_channel: '%https%' }
```

I found out you can add multiple roles and this worked:

```
 access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/stats, roles: [ROLE_EXPL,ROLE_ADMIN], requires_channel: '%https%' }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: '%https%' }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: '%https%' }
        - { path: ^/forgotten_password, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: '%https%' }
        - { path: ^/reset_password, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: '%https%' }
```

Answer (score 1):

If any user with the role `ROLE_EXPL` should have access to `/admin/stats`, you need to change the `access_control` settings. Currently it says:

```
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: '%https%' }
```

...which means: only users with the role `ROLE_ADMIN` have access to the paths starting with `/admin`

Comment: Yes it looks like the developer missed another line for the path /admin/stats; So do you think this I should add this line above or below the one above?  { path: ^/admin/stats, roles: ROLE_EXPL, requires_channel: '%https%' } 
 
Any chance you could clarify that by amending the anwser, thanks :)

Comment: I cannot decide whether you **should** do that. If it resolves your problem, go for it - but I cannot tell you whether this opens up this route to other users who should not have access to it or not

Comment: Ok, I tried to add it above but it didnt work, so I added it below, and it worked but then broke for the other user.